# How to add column when the number of columns in file is 2

Tags: linux, awk, csv-simple

I am trying to write `awk` for a file I have. Example of the dataset is

```
S,CV0110,1235
S,1234
D,CQ120,3245
P,7894
```

Desired outcome is as follows (added empty field when the number of fields in a row is 2)

```
S,CV0110,1235
S,,1234
D,CQ120,3245
P,,7894
```

I tried this but it is adding value for all data rows instead of those that have 2 fields.

```
printf 'S,CV010,1235\r\n' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"}{$n = $n OFS value}1'
```

Comment: So we can explain where you went wrong, what were you hoping that setting `FS` to `"fs"` would do?

Answer (score 6):

Given

```
$ cat file
S,CV0110,1235
S,1234
D,CQ120,3245
P,7894
```

then

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} NF<3{$1 = $1 OFS} 1' file
S,CV0110,1235
S,,1234
D,CQ120,3245
P,,7894
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sed '/,.*,/!s/,/,,/' file
```

- `/,.*,/!` If line does not contain two commas,
- `s/,/,,/` Substitute the first comma by two commas.

This can be generalized to more fields. E.g., to add an empty field if some line is missing the 7th field,

```
sed -E '/,(.*,){5}/!s/,/,,/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the values en each column are always similar.

If a single letter at the start of the line is followed by 4 numbers and the line ends, add a comma:

```
sed '/^[A-Z],[0-9]\{4\}$/s/,/,,/' file
```

Output:

```
S,CV0110,1235
S,,1234
D,CQ120,3245
P,,7894
```